# Custom data-dependent recoding to logicals in R

Tags: r, data-conversion, data-management

I have two data frames, `data` and `meta`. Some, but not all, columns in `data` are logical values, but they are coded in many different ways. The rows in `meta` describe the columns in `data`, indicate whether they are to be interpreted as logicals, and if so, what single value codes TRUE and what single value codes FALSE.

I need a procedure that replaces all `data` values in conceptually logical columns with the appropriate logical values from the codes in the corresponding `meta` row. Any `data` values in a conceptually logical column that do not match a value in the corresponding `meta` row should become NA.

Small toy example for `meta`:

```
name                 type     false  true
-----------------------------------------
a.char.var           char     NA     NA
a.logical.var        logical  NA     7
another.logical.var  logical  1      0
another.char.var     char     NA     NA
```

Small toy example for `data`:

```
a.char.var  a.logical.var  another.logical.var  another.char.var
----------------------------------------------------------------
aa          7              0                    ba
ab          NA             1                    bb
ac          7              NA                   bc
ad          4              3                    bd
```

Small toy example output:

```
a.char.var  a.logical.var  another.logical.var  another.char.var
----------------------------------------------------------------
aa          TRUE           TRUE                 ba
ab          FALSE          FALSE                bb
ac          TRUE           NA                   bc
ad          NA             NA                   bd
```

I cannot, for the life of me, find a way to do this in idiomatic R that handles all the corner cases. The data sets are large, so an idiomatic solution would be ideal if possible. I inherited this absolutely insane data management mess and will be grateful to anybody who can help fix it. I am by no means an R guru, but this seems like a deceptively difficult problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we set up the data

```
meta <- data.frame(name=c('a.char.var', 'a.logical.var', 'another.logical.var', 'another.char.var'),
                   type=c('char', 'logical', 'logical', 'char'),
                   false=c(NA, NA, 1, NA),
                   true=c(NA, 7, 0, NA), stringsAsFactors = F)

data <- data.frame(a.char.var=c('aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad'),
                   a.logical.var=c(7, NA, 7, 4),
                   another.logical.var=c(0,1,NA,3),
                   another.char.var=c('ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'bd'), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Then we subset out just the logical columns.  We will iterate through these, using the `name` column to select the relevant column in `data`, and change values in `data_out` from an initialized `NA` to either `T` or `F` according to matching values in `data`.

Note that `data[,logical_meta$name[1]]` is equivalent to `data[,'a.logical.var']` or `data$a.logical.var`, if `logical_meta$name` is a character.  If it's a factor (eg if we didn't specify `stringsAsFactors=F`) we need to convert to character at which point we might as well give it a name - `colname` below.

Having NAs to contend with means using `which` is advantageous: `c(0, 1,NA,3)==0` returns `T,F,NA,F` but `which` then ignores the `NA` and returns just the position `1`.  Subsetting by a logical vector that includes NAs yields NA rows or columns, using `which` eliminates this.

```
logical_meta <- meta[meta$type=='logical',]

data_out <- data #initialize


for(i in 1:nrow(logical_meta)) {
  colname <- as.character(logical_meta$name[i]) #only need as.character if factor
  data_out[,colname] <- NA
  #false column first
  if(is.na(logical_meta$false[i])) {
    data_out[is.na(data[,colname]),colname] <- FALSE
  } else {
    data_out[which(data[,colname]==logical_meta$false[i]),
             colname] <- FALSE
  }
  #true column next
  if(is.na(logical_meta$true[i])) {
    data_out[is.na(data[,colname]),colname] <- TRUE
  } else {
    data_out[which(data[,colname]==logical_meta$true[i]),
             colname] <- TRUE
  }
}

data_out
```

Comment: Thank you. This is fairly elegant and easy to understand. The row iteration makes me feel a bit dirty (probably my lack of experience surrounding when to seek vectorization in R). Is a meaningfully vectorized solution possible for this? Is there a reason that `data_out[is.na(data[,colname]),logical_meta$name[i]] <- TRUE` isn't `data_out[is.na(data[,colname]),colname] <- TRUE` as it is for FALSE? Why is the "which" necessary in the subsetting? I'll wait awhile longer and then accept if this remains the best.

Comment: Good catch, I was swapping `logical_meta$name[i]` over to `colname` and missed that one

Comment: Unless you have tons of columns this should be fairly quick.  The assignments are vectorized, with three per column (1. to NA, 2. setting all 'false's to F, 3. setting all 'true's to T) regardless of number of rows.

Comment: Just saw that. Also, I can't believe I didn't think to make a temporary copy of the data for this, like you did. That was hanging me up with a lot of my attempts. All right. Good show!

Answer (score 0):

I've written a function that takes in the column index of `data` and tries to perform the operation you described.

The function first selects `x` as the column we are interested in. We then match the name of the column in `data` to the entries in the first column of `meta`, this gives our row of interest.

We then check if the column type is `logical`, if it isn't we just return `x`, nothing needed to be changed. If the column type is `logical` we then check whether its values match the `true` or `false` columns in `meta`.

```
convert_data <- function(colindex, dat, meta = meta){
    x <- dat[,colindex] #select our data vector

    #match the column name to the first column in meta
    find_in_meta <- match(names(dat)[colindex],
                          meta[,1])

    #what type of column is it
    type_col <- meta[find_in_meta,2]

    if(type_col != 'logical'){
        return(x)
    }else{
        #fix if logical is NA
        true_val <- ifelse(is.na(meta[find_in_meta,4]),'NA_val',
                           meta[find_in_meta,4])

        #fix if logical is NA
        false_val <- ifelse(is.na(meta[find_in_meta,3]), 'NA_val',
                            meta[find_in_meta, 3])

        #fix if logical is NA
        x <- ifelse(is.na(x), 'NA_val', x)
        x <- ifelse(x == true_val, TRUE,
               ifelse(x == false_val, FALSE, NA))
        return(x)
    }
}
```

We can then use `lapply` and a little data manipulation to get it into an acceptable form:

```
res <- lapply(1:ncol(df1), function(ind) 
                      convert_data(colindex = ind, dat = df1, meta = meta))

setNames(do.call('cbind.data.frame', res), names(df1))

  a.char.var a.logical.var another.logical.var another.char.var
1         aa          TRUE                TRUE               ba
2         ab         FALSE               FALSE               bb
3         ac          TRUE                  NA               bc
4         ad            NA                  NA               bd
```

#### data

```
meta <- structure(list(name = c("a.char.var", "a.logical.var", "another.logical.var", 
"another.char.var"), type = c("char", "logical", "logical", "char"
), false = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA), true = c(NA, 7L, 0L, NA)), .Names = c("name", 
"type", "false", "true"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df1 <- structure(list(a.char.var = c("aa", "ab", "ac", "ad"), a.logical.var = c(7L, 
NA, 7L, 4L), another.logical.var = c(0L, 1L, NA, 3L), another.char.var = c("ba", 
"bb", "bc", "bd")), .Names = c("a.char.var", "a.logical.var", 
"another.logical.var", "another.char.var"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Maybe not the most straightforward solution but it works - I don't see a reason for the downvote...

Comment: Thank you for the response! For now, I prefer the answer by @ds440 for brevity and elegance.